# Jquery Javascript - Make inline js a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Ok so this i probably very easy but i can't seem to figure it out.  I have a a function but i still have to call the function inline.  I am wondering if there is a way to put it all in the function. Right now my function looks like this:

```
function ddItem(el) {
 $(el).closest(".ddSelectHeader").find("input").attr({
    value : $(el).text()
})
 }
```

Then i call this function inline like this:

```
<div class="ddContainer">
<div class="ddSelectHeader"><input name="" type="text" />
<div class="ddSubmenu">
  <a href="#" onclick="ddItem(this)">Item 1</a><br />
  <a href="#" onclick="ddItem(this)">item 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ok so i am trying to make a simple drop down but with divs instead of the traditional ul li.  The way it is written above works fine but i was hoping there is a way to take the onlcick out so that any link that is click within the ddSubmenu will populate the input field.  This way i don't have to call it inline or in the html.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ddSubmenu a").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.closest(".ddSelectHeader").find("input").val($this.text());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('.ddSubmenu > a').click(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.closest(".ddSelectHeader").find("input").val(self.text());
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for value, I fixed the structure but missed what he was actually setting.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - You can still modify your answer and make it better.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Will do.  Always feel funny amending my answer based on someone elses prior to an answer being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Via javascript, you can use `element.onclick`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick

or jQuery's `.click()`: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ddSubmenu a').click(function(){
    ddItem(this);
});
```